Replacement character in text
This application is created in NodeJs (ElectronJs)
There is a problem with the text in html, instead of spaces/indents, black diamonds with a question mark inside (replacement character) appear
Here are some screen shots until I figure out how to post code



Perhaps this is due to the fact that my system language is Russian

I tried to find a solution on the Internet, but it seems like I’m looking in the wrong place, or there’s quite a bit of information about it

Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a Stacksnippet Please do NOT just post images of code.
